# django chain list objects filter

Tags: python, django

I want to collect all the models of all my applications and then filter them but I am having the following error :

```
AttributeError at /search 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
Request Method: GET Request
URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?category=1&submit=%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%AF%D8%A7+%DA%A9%D9%86%21
Django Version: 2.1.7 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value: 
'list' object has no attribute 'filter' Exception
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app_adventure.models import *
from app_cultural.models import *
from app_children.models import *
from app_base.choices import Tour_type_choices, Destination_choices, Day_choices, Month_choices
from itertools import chain


# Create your views here.


# search


def search(request):
    adventure = AdventureTor.objects.all()
    cultural = CulturalTor.objects.all()
    children = ChildTor.objects.all()
    queryset_list = list(chain(adventure, cultural, children))

    # search by category
    if 'category' in request.GET:
        category = request.GET['category']
        if category:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(category__icontains=category)  # mitonest iexact bashe

    context = {
        'Tour_type_choices': Tour_type_choices,
        'Destination_choices': Destination_choices,
        'Day_choices': Day_choices,
        'Month_choices': Month_choices,
        'search': queryset_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter a chain as it is not an SQL query anymore. You may try filtering those 3 queries individually, then use `chain()`. For example:

```
def search(request):
    my_queries = [AdventureTor.objects.all(),
                  CulturalTor.objects.all(),
                  ChildTor.objects.all()]

    # search by category
    if 'category' in request.GET:
        category = request.GET['category']
        if category:
            my_queries = [query.filter(category__icontains=category) 
                          for query in my_queries]

    queryset_list = list(chain(**my_queries))
    context = {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
But
Answer with two stars
type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
There are no answers without stars
There is an answer with a star, but based on the error category
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:
Can not resolve keyword 'category' to field. Choices are: Location_and_time_of_movement, Number_Of_Days, Summary, capacity, catering,  description, id, is_published, list_date, not_included, picture, price, residence, returning_time, services, state, tag, title

Comment: Thanks again
Excuse me, it was a problem with me
Just this piece of code
queryset_list = list (chain (** my_queries))
Instead of placing two stars, the problem was completely solved
thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=Comment.objects.all()
>>> b=Site.objects.all()        
>>> c=[a,b]
>>> c.filter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
>>> a.filter()
[<Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, <Comment: Comment object>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>> b.filter()
[<Site: Site object>, <Site: Site object>, <Site: Site object>, <Site: Site object>]
```

As the error says filter your queryset before you append

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer
But I did not understand
I'm looking for the answer to how my work should be done

Comment: fix the error and append all the queryset to your list